# ExtJS Ajax Call

Tags: php, ajax, extjs

Newbie ask:

Did I miss something?

**Loaded scripts**

`http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js`
`http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/ext-all.js`

**Code**

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '<?php $template_url."/raw-post.php" ?>',
        params: { Xc : 0, Xp : <?php echo '84'; ?> },
        success: function( result, request ){
            Ext.get('test').dom.innerHTML = result.responseText;
        }
    });
});
```

**raw-post.php**

`echo "this is response text";`

**Firebug error**

`e is undefined; window.undefined=window.undefined;Ext=...window.attachEvent("onunload",a)}})();`

**Chrome error**

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined`

===================

**Updated/Fixed**

Sorry, my bad. I missed `echo` here `url: '<?php $template_url."/raw-post.php" ?>',`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I missed `echo` here `url: '<?php $template_url."/raw-post.php" ?>',`